# Multiple ECMA-Script versions in intellij idea

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using Intellij IDEA to develop a Node.js Application.
I'm using es5 in the frontend and es6 in the backend.

Is there a way to define ECMAScript level per folder?

Thanks

Comment: Have different .eslintrc for each folder.

Comment: This works for eslint but I still get Intellij errors like `var used instead of let or const` in frontend.

Comment: There's eslint rule for that, too. http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-var . To my knowledge, IDE relies on eslint for that.

Comment: Might be, but that doesn't solve my problem. With the .eslintrc in the folder Intellij still thinks it should be es6.

Comment: You probably need to add your eslintrc files to the question then, this may help.

Comment: I'm talking about Native Intellij inspection not eslint. Anyway: https://gist.github.com/rolandg/9d1f175b0180725fbc6e787b509f5868
https://gist.github.com/rolandg/6c62760af1858d27e9962385791f661d

Comment: @BhargavRao Why was the correct answer deleted? The stated reason, 'same answer to multiple questions' is wrong, and the link to 'duplicate' answer wasn't provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the new versions of the [JetBrains](http://jetbrains.com) IDES (iDea, WebStorm, and so on) you can configure different JavaScript language versions for different folders.

For example, if you’re working on a JavaScript project that uses both ECMAScript 5.1 and newer ECMAScript version or JSX or Flow, you now have two options for how to configure it in WebStorm.

To configure different JavaScript language versions for different folders,
you need to go to *Preferences | Languages and Frameworks | JavaScript* menu and click the on `…` button next to the drop-down with the version, then select a folder and the language version used for its files:

[image]

The version specified on the main settings page will be applied by default for all other JavaScript files in the project.

Ref. [WebStorm blog#multiple-js-versions](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/09/webstorm-2017-3-eap-173-2463/#multiple-js-versions)

Answer (score 1):

If multiple ECMAScript versions are used, then common denominator should be picked for the project, `ECMAScript 6`.

JetBrains IDEs rely on ESLint for linting, so different .eslintrc configurations can be provided per folder, i.e.

```
{
    "env": {
        "es6": false,
        ...
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "rules": {
        "no-var": 0,
        ...
    }
}
```

for frontend, and

```
{
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        ...
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "rules": {
        "no-var": 1,
        ...
    }
}
```

for backend.

In this case all inspections that interfere with ESLint rules are supposed to be [disabled](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html), like `var used instead of let or const`.

Comment: This is NOT a correct answer, the original question was about Webstorm own inspections, not ESLint. If inspections like `var used instead of let or const` is the only issue, the solution is setting up inspection scopes. But disabling inspections or setting up the scope won't help to get rid of syntax errors when using ES6 syntax in a project with JavaScript version set to `ES5`, for example

Comment: @lena It addresses the problem that the user has, i.e. maintaining several roots with different ES versions and rulesets in a single project. I believe this the only way how it can be done now (did this already myself). And I have a feeling that IDE itself uses ESLint internally at least for some inspections, e.g. `var used...`. Not sure if there are pitfalls when relying on ESLint instead of inspections for intersecting rules, I've seen none. I don't know why your answer was deleted, it doesn't help the problem but answers the question precisely.

Comment: I can tell for sure that the IDE doesn't use ESLint internally (though it can run it via ESLint integration). and, as i have mentioned, setting up ESLint won't help with built-in inspections/lexer issues